# Cannot populate Hover Tooltip values in bokeh network plot

Tags: python, networking, plot, graph, bokeh

I have a network, with nodes as such:

```
[('user_0', {'pk': 2, 'tname': 'user_0'}), ('user_1', {'pk': 3, 'tname': 'user_1'}), ('user_2', {'pk': 4, 'tname': 'user_2'}), ('user_3', {'pk': 5, 't': 'user_3'}), ('user_4', {'pk': 6, 't': 'user_4'})]
```

And my plotting code [is essentially a combination of the two examples in the documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html).  It's as follows:

```
        # Create plot
    plot = Plot(plot_width=600, 
                plot_height=600,
                x_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1), 
                y_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1))

    # Set title
    plot.title.text = "Graph Interaction Demonstration"

    # Create and set up graph renderer ------------------------------------
    # Use renderer to plot from network x, with given layout
    graph = self.as_plottable()

    nodes = list(graph .nodes)
    n_nodes = len(list(graph .nodes))
    graph_renderer = from_networkx(graph ,
                                   nx.shell_layout,
                                   nlist=[nodes[0:int(n_nodes/3)], 
                                          nodes[int(n_nodes/3):2*int(n_nodes/3)],
                                          nodes[2*int(n_nodes/3):]],
                                   scale=1, 
                                   center=(0,0))

    # Add interaction tools
    node_hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips=[
            ('Name','@tname'),
            ('ID','@pk')
            ])
    plot.add_tools(node_hover_tool, 
                   BoxZoomTool(),
                   ResetTool())

    graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=8, fill_color=Spectral4[0])
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.selection_glyph = Circle(size=8, fill_color=Spectral4[2])
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.hover_glyph = Circle(size=12, fill_color=Spectral4[1])

    graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color="#BFBFBF", line_alpha=0.8, line_width=3)
    graph_renderer.edge_renderer.selection_glyph = MultiLine(line_color=Spectral4[2], line_width=3)
    graph_renderer.edge_renderer.hover_glyph = MultiLine(line_color=Spectral4[1], line_width=3)

    # Provide logic for selection of graph components
    graph_renderer.selection_policy = NodesAndLinkedEdges()

    # Provide logic for inspection of graph components
    graph_renderer.inspection_policy = EdgesAndLinkedNodes()

    # Add network graph renderer to plot
    plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)

    # Output graph to a file
    output_file(filename)

    # Plot graph
    show(plot)
```

I've tried shuffling around the order of things, changing the names of my node attributes, and various other adjustments, but my hovertip data always displays as "Name: ???", "ID: ???".  I've read that this can happen when you don't actually have the right columns in your data source, but I printed the dict:

```
graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source.data
```

And it had entries for both "tname" and "pk".  I'm stumped.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Solved it, the problem was setting my inspection policy to `EdgesAndLinkedNodes()`.  This was causing my tooltips to look for information in the edges, rather than the nodes.