# How to pass in Node attributes to HoverTool tooltips when using Holoviews' from_networkx method

Tags: networkx, bokeh, holoviews

new to holoviews, bokeh and networkx.

I'm trying to build a visualisation where I reveal all the node attributes on hover. I'm building the graph with networkx, and using Holoviews' from_networkx method to import to the holoviews graph class.

I've seen this which is relevant (i.e. node attributes are now imported when using from_networkx):
https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/issues/2696

However, I'm struggling to reference the node attributes in the tool tips.
This is the code using the karate club example, which works:

```
%%opts Graph [color_index='circle']
%%opts Graph (node_size=5 edge_line_width=1)
%opts Graph [width=900 height=900]

colours = ['#000000']+hv.Cycle('Category20').values

G_kcg = nx.karate_club_graph()

hover_kcg = HoverTool(tooltips=[("Club", "@club")])

plot_kcg = hv.Graph.from_networkx(G_kcg, nx.spring_layout)
plot_kcg = plot_kcg.options(cmap=colours,tools=[hover_kcg])

bundled = bundle_graph(plot_kcg)
bundled
```

However, switching in my own dataset, it just returns '???' in the tool tip:

```
%%opts Graph [color_index='circle']
%%opts Graph (node_size=5 edge_line_width=1)
%opts Graph [width=900 height=900]

colours = ['#000000']+hv.Cycle('Category20').values

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("Name", "@crew_name")])

plot_all = hv.Graph.from_networkx(G_all, nx.spring_layout)
plot_all = plot_all.options(cmap=colours,tools=[hover])

bundled = bundle_graph(plot_all)
bundled
```

The NodeDataView output for both graphs looks to be of the same format to me:

```
G_kcg.nodes(data=True)
```

> NodeDataView({0: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 1: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 2: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 3: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 4: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 5: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 6: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 7: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 8: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 9: {'club': 'Officer'}, 10: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 11: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 12: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 13: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 14: {'club': 'Officer'}, 15: {'club': 'Officer'}, 16: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 17: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 18: {'club': 'Officer'}, 19: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 20: {'club': 'Officer'}, 21: {'club': 'Mr. Hi'}, 22: {'club': 'Officer'}, 23: {'club': 'Officer'}, 24: {'club': 'Officer'}, 25: {'club': 'Officer'}, 26: {'club': 'Officer'}, 27: {'club': 'Officer'}, 28: {'club': 'Officer'}, 29: {'club': 'Officer'}, 30: {'club': 'Officer'}, 31: {'club': 'Officer'}, 32: {'club': 'Officer'}, 33: {'club': 'Officer'}})

```
G_all.nodes(data=True)
```

> NodeDataView({12240216: {'crew_name': u'a'}, ...  8421367: {'crew_name': u'b'}})

Apologies if I've not made the problem clear at all, would appreciate any help I can get as I've been bashing my head at this one for hours on end!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try: [Cannot populate Hover Tooltip values in bokeh network plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680572/cannot-populate-hover-tooltip-values-in-bokeh-network-plot)

You may try setting inspection_policy to "nodes"

Alternatively, you can add this to/from attributes to the edges and then use inspection_policy 'edges'

Here is a basic example of using the edge approach

```
G = nx.karate_club_graph()

nx.set_edge_attributes(G,'','from')
nx.set_edge_attributes(G,'','to')
for edge in G.edges:
    G.edges.get(edge)['from']=G.nodes.get(edge[0])['club']
    G.edges.get(edge)['to']=G.nodes.get(edge[1])['club']

hover_kcg = HoverTool(tooltips=[("From", "@from"),("To","@to")])

hv.Graph.from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout).opts(
    tools=[hover_kcg],
    inspection_policy='edges'    #this is where you'll want to double check
)
```

-or-

```
hover_kcg = HoverTool(tooltips=[("Club", "@club")])
hv.Graph.from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout).opts(
    tools=[hover_kcg],
    inspection_policy='nodes'    
)
```